# Android - Facebook SDK 3 - Wall post only

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-wall

I am new to Facebook SDK (3) and have succesfully compiled and run the HelloFacebookSample. Now I want to only publish a wall post so I triedy to delete all the unnecessary stuff and only have the post status functionality

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    postStatusUpdateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.postStatusUpdateButton);
    postStatusUpdateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onClickPostStatusUpdate();
        }
    });
}

private void onClickPostStatusUpdate() {
    performPublish(PendingAction.POST_STATUS_UPDATE);
}

private void performPublish(PendingAction action) {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null) {
        pendingAction = action;
        if (hasPublishPermission()) {
            // We can do the action right away.
            handlePendingAction();
        } else {
            // We need to reauthorize, then complete the action when we get called back.
             Session.ReauthorizeRequest reauthRequest = new Session.ReauthorizeRequest(this, PERMISSIONS).
                        setRequestCode(REAUTHORIZE_ACTIVITY).
                        setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SSO_WITH_FALLBACK);
            session.reauthorizeForPublish(reauthRequest);
        }
    }
}
```

However on performPublish session is null.

Comment: Are you still using the LoginButton to perform login? That's what sets and opens the active session.

Comment: You'll have check where the session instance is supposed to be instantiated and see why it is null. The code above is not where the error is.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue myself. The Session is null because the user is not logged in; the user must be logged in before calling reauthorizeRequest or sending a Request.

One approach is to make sure the user clicks the LoginButton and logs in successfully; if they are not logged in when they attempt to publish a status update (session is null) then you should show an AlertDialog telling them to sign in--or better yet, bringing up the sign-in dialog.

LoginButton is a nice convenience tool, but unfortunately Facebook just gives you the choice between using the LoginButton exactly as it is or writing everything from scratch itself. But you can see the important code if you open LoginButton in Eclipse:

```
Session currentSession = sessionTracker.getSession();
                if (currentSession == null || currentSession.getState().isClosed()) {
                    sessionTracker.setSession(null);
                    Session session = new Session.Builder(context).setApplicationId(applicationId).build();
                    Session.setActiveSession(session);
                    currentSession = session;
                }
                if (!currentSession.isOpened()) {
                    Session.OpenRequest openRequest = null;
                    if (parentFragment != null) {
                        openRequest = new Session.OpenRequest(parentFragment);
                    } else if (context instanceof Activity) {
                        openRequest = new Session.OpenRequest((Activity)context);
                    }

                    if (openRequest != null) {
                        openRequest.setPermissions(permissions);
                        openRequest.setLoginBehavior(loginBehavior);

                        if (SessionAuthorizationType.PUBLISH.equals(authorizationType)) {
                            currentSession.openForPublish(openRequest);
                        } else {
                            currentSession.openForRead(openRequest);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

This is the code to log in (that is, to bring up the login screen so the user can log in). You can use the SessionTracker yourself, but I think that Facebook may not mean for people to use that (it isn't in the SDK documentation and the package is com.facebook.internal, implying they don't want developers using it)--but you can adjust the code to your needs.

Comment: I just want to share some content to Facebook since the ACTION_SEND is broken, but thanks. Ill look into it now.

Comment: In your original question you complained that session was null. Is your question about fixing that, or how to publish to the logged-in user's wall?

Comment: Well the whole idea is to share some string to FB via their SDK after action item click, so I grabbed the example and tried to remove all the for me unnecessary stuff and it didnt work so I tried to debug the code and found out that the session is null, which is as you said, because user never logged in

Comment: Okay I am currently working at it, ... Isnt there an easier way to just login, programatically? Thats a bit crazy that the only standard way to login is using their LoginButton...

Comment: LoginButton is the only easy way--but as I showed above, you can use the same code the LoginButton does. At least all we have to do is open a session, and Facebook handles the UI, authentication, etc--it just looks a little complex in the code example because you have to be prepared for a few possibilities.